Firebase storage security rules error unauthorized
I'm trying to add a document to Firebase storage with this security rule
match /TrabajosResumenes/{trabajoID}/{allPaths=**}  {
  allow create: if request.auth != null && (
    firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID))/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.trabajos_crear == true ||

    request.auth.uid in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID))/Trabajos/$(trabajoID)).data.empleados ||

    request.auth.uid == firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID))).data.uid_nagusia
      );
}

function GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID) {
  return firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/TrabajosResumenes/$(trabajoID)).data.uid_empresa;           
} 

In a given case for a user, the first condition is false, but the other two are true and even though I use the OR clause, it doesn't work.
But if I change the order of the conditions it works:
allow create: if request.auth != null && (

  request.auth.uid in firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID))/Trabajos/$(trabajoID)).data.empleados ||
  firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID))/empleados/$(request.auth.uid)).data.trabajos_crear == true ||
  request.auth.uid == firestore.get(/databases/(default)/documents/negocios/$(GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID))).data.uid_nagusia
    );

I don't really understand how the OR clause works in Firestorage. First a document is created correctly and once uploaded I try to save the file
The rules to create the document in Firestore are practically the same, except that I use the variable request.resource.data.uid_empresa instead of GetEmpresaTrabajo(trabajoID).
My question is if anyone knows of an example that uses two get requests in which one of them is false. That using the " || " clause should work.
